# Qt c++ two-factor authentication

Tags: c++, qt

I am developing a Qt application which requires the user to login in to use the application. I want to use two factor authentication, a password and a usb stick being the two forms of authentication.

Are there any Qt libraries that support encryption, and what is the most secure way hash/encrypt and store a password and private/public keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt offers built-in cryptographic hashing via the [QCryptographicHash](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qcryptographichash.html) class. It supports MD5, SHA-1, and SHA-512, at least. MD5 is awful, and SHA-1 is old. I'd say to use either SHA-256 or SHA-512... both are very hard to brute force with current technology.

No matter where you store the password, you'll want to save it with a (lengthy) salt. Any random string will do.

One possible way to do two-factor authentication might be to store the salt on a USB stick so that your program doesn't know how to decrypt the password unless the salt file is present. This is more-or-less what pam_usb does in Linux. (pam_usb uses a one-time pad, you can read the [source](https://github.com/aluzzardi/pam_usb/blob/master/src/pad.c).)